# How to authorize colab with Github?

Tags: github, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

When selecting option on Google colab "Save a copy on Github" I receive message :

[image]

From reading https://medium.com/tensorflow/colab-an-easy-way-to-learn-and-use-tensorflow-d74d1686e309 this option should be available ?

Should another an Github authorization link appear as part of above authorization popup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving notebook to github in colab is a simple two step process. Just click `Save a copy in github` and `authorize googlecolab for git`.

***The first popup :***
[image]

***The second popup :*** (only if popup-windows are blocked in your browser)
[image]

***The third popup :*** (click retry in second window OR it will open directly after first click)
[image]

Authorize and proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Did you block popups? The GitHub authorization window is a popup. If you're using Chrome, there will be a button in the address bar that appears to permit the auth popup.